# The python Selenium method "driver.get('https.....') is not working with Twitter.com?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, twitter

**Environment:**

Python 3.7.7
geckodriver 0.28
Selenium 3.141

**Problem:**

When I open twitter.com URL with Python Selenium Geckodriver (Firefox), the firefox browser is opening but URL is not showing in the URL field and the program sleep.... nothing is happening. no exit error message in the terminal.
So I tested with other websites like google.fr, Linkedin and it worked perfectly well with the local firefox profiles loaded in Selenium driver. I successfully open session with user logged in.

But it doesn't work with https://twitter.com

When I type by hand 'https://twitter.com' in the URL field of selenium driver, the Twitter website is loading well.

I tested with Chrome and I don't have issue. It is working fine.

All these tests were realized with geckodriver 0.26
So I download and replace it with 0.28 version. I have the exact same issue.

As a resume, it seems Twitter is  blocking geckodriver (not Chrome).

Please, does anyone can simply copy-paste my python code and test it on his computer to see there is the same issue?

**Screenshot:**

[image]

You can easily reproduce the issue with this code:

**Code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import FirefoxProfile


#Little function to get Firefox profiles
def all_subdirs_of(b='.'):
    """
    This function return all the subdirectories of a directory
    """

    result = []
    for d in os.listdir(b):
        bd = os.path.join(b, d)
        if os.path.isdir(bd): result.append(bd)
    return result

# Getting Firefox profile
firefox_profile_folder_path = appdata =os.environ['APPDATA'] + "\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles"
latest_profile = max(all_subdirs_of(firefox_profile_folder_path), key=os.path.getmtime)

print(latest_profile)
profile = FirefoxProfile(latest_profile)

#Getting the driver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
print(driver.name)
driver.get("https://twitter.com")
```

**Output:**

C:\User

```
s\Nino\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\nvqh3f1a.default-1576999507190
firefox
```

**UPDATE:**

After a few minutes, I get an output exit 1 message in the terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 61, in <module>
    driver.get("https://twitter.com")
  File "C:\Users\Nino\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Users\Nino\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Nino\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Comment: Twitter might be blocking you for running an automated browser. There are some ways around this. Should you be trying to use the twitter API instead of the browser?

Comment: Thanks for helping. The twitter api has limited features. I need to automate some specific stuff.

Comment: I'm really don't know why this error happening but the thing you are trying is not gonna happen. They will definitely block you after some time. so don't waste time on this thing instead try twitter API.

Comment: @Darkknight, "after some time" might be 5 years, if your app is "polite", maintains session, does not spam etc.  - personal experience.